# OneToMany (bidirectional) not inserting foreign key in child table while saving

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

foreign key is not saving into the task table association is not forming while saving the holder through the rest api.
Please let me known what i am missing here

REST API 
URL : localhost:8080/priority/holder

PAYLOAD :
{
  "name": "Madhu",
  "task": [
    {
      "name": "update",
      "type": "Technical"
    },
    {
      "name": "jogg",
      "type": "fitness"
    },
    {
      "name": "work",
      "type": "project"
    }
  ]
}

Here i am adding my controller,entities and service images

[Controller][1]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/priority")
public class TaskController {
    @Autowired
    TaskService taskService;
    @PostMapping(value = "/holder")
    public Holder createHolder(@RequestBody Holder holder) {
        return taskService.createHolder(holder);
    }
}

@Service
public class TaskService {
    @Autowired
    TaskRepositriy taskRepo;
    @Autowired
    HolderRepositry holderRepo;
    public Holder createHolder(Holder holder) {
        return holderRepo.save(holder);
    }

}

@Entity
public class Holder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "holder",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Task> task;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Task> getTask() {
        return task;
    }
    public void setTask(List<Task> task) {
        this.task = task;
    }   
}

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="holder_task")
    private Holder holder;
    public Holder getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }
    public void setHolder(Holder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Werner Thanks provided the code in the images

Comment: Could you please insert the code as text into your question? Someone might want to copy the code in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @wener done added code as text

Comment: Set holder's reference in Task before saving.. that should work

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43806173/2129801) contains a very similar problem, unfortunately without an accepted answer. An option might be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37951699/2129801), but this would require to run two rest calls.